# Python import from another package not working: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python-3.x, import

I read here [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) that **init**.py is not needed for importing modules from other packages in python versions above 3.3. I have created a dummy program to try out importing.
Here is the file structure:

```
package_1
  |
   --- module1.py

package_2
  |
   --- module2.py
```

module1.py:

```
class Class1():
    def __init__(self):
        print("In module 1")
```

module2.py

```
from package_1.module1 import Class1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c1 = Class1()
    print("Working in Class2")
```

I get the following error when I run module2.py:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_1'
```

Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

The same is working for me , please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I am using python 3.7.3 and running it on the command line via python3 command.